# Update Database from DataGridView on Event does not work properly

Tags: c#, sql, database, datagridview, sql-update

I have a DataGridView which is populated from a database.
I have a button to save the changes from the DGV into the database, this works fine.
But now I wanted the database to update automatically if someting was changed in the DGV.

I tried several events as CellEndEdit, CellLeave, CellValidated, CellValueChanged and SelectionChanged.
If I edited the cells content and hit enter or clicked/selected a cell above or beneath it worked fine, the changes were saved into the database, but if I hit tab or clicked/selected a cell next to it in the same row, the changes were not saved. None of the above mentioned events helped me with this problem.

//EDIT

some sample code:

I fill my DGV like this

```
query_em = "select * from Table;";
try
{
    dt_em = new DataTable();
    da_em = new OleDbDataAdapter(query_em, connString);
    cb_em = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da_em);
    bs_em = new BindingSource();

    da_em.Fill(dt_em);
    bs_em.DataSource = dt_em;
    dgv_em.DataSource = bs_em;
    dgv_em.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    throw;
}
```

Normally I update them with a button

```
private void bt_save_em_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            da_em.Update(dt_em);
            MessageBox.Show("Database updated.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

But I would like to have something like this working properly, but it doesnt. The exact problem is described above.

```
private void dgv_em_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        da_em.Update(dt_em);
    }
```

Comment: please show us some sample code so we can help

Comment: added some code, i dont see how this could help, but go ahead ;)
i need another event then the above described. the code is okay so far i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old question but i've found a solution that may help some people.
In fact the datagridview (lets call it dgv, i'm lazy ^^ ) validate the input and update the datasource only when you change row (by pressing enter, arrows, clicking etc.)
So the event to use is `RowValidated`.
But this event won't fire if you stay in the same row after editing, for example if you click on a cell in the same row. I've foud a solution to force the validation: use another event and call `this.validate` (`me.validate` in vb)

Here is some vb sample code (as i said before, i'm too lazy to convert in c# ^^ ), i hope this will help:

```
Public Class Form1
   Dim ValueChanged As Boolean
   Dim da As MySqlDataAdapter

   [...]

Private Sub dgv_CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv.CellValueChanged
    ValueChanged = True
End Sub

//not sure this one is still usefull, i'm still working on this stuff :)
Private Sub dgv_RowValidated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv.RowValidated
    If ValueChanged Then
        ValueChanged = False
        da.Update(dt)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub dgv_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dgv.SelectionChanged
    If ValueChanged Then
        ValueChanged = False
        Me.Validate()
        da.Update(dt)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use CellEndEdit:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

try
        {
            da_em.Update(dt_em);
            MessageBox.Show("Database updated.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }

        }
```

Comment: as i mentioned in my question:
*quote*
I tried several events as CellEndEdit, CellLeave, CellValidated, CellValueChanged and SelectionChanged.
*/quote*